# Convert PHP array from dates to week numbers

Tags: php, arrays

I have the below output from my Array:

[JSFiddle Array](https://jsfiddle.net/h39rh59x/)

I have the following code:

```
    $uniquePids = array_unique(array_map(function ($i) { return $i['0']; }, $arrayOpenPW));
    $numberOfArrs = count($arrayOpenPW);
    $pids = array();

    foreach ($arrayOpenPW as $h) {
        $pids[] = $h['0'];
    }

    print_r($uniquePids);
```

The variable `$uniquePids` only shows non-duplicate dates within that array. The output on JsFiddle is from the `$uniquePids` array.

Next I want to loop through each result in the `$uniquePids` array and convert each element within that array from dates to week numbers. How do I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to make use of the "strototime" and "date" functions in PHP. Assuming that $h['0'] represents a single full date string (e.g. 04/04/2016), then...

```
foreach ($arrayOpenPW as $h) {
   $pids[] = date("W", strotime($h['0']));
}
```

This will convert the text inside $h['0'] into a numerical timestamp, which you then parse with "date" to get parameters you want. "W" in this case represents which week of the year it is, numerically. http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php will show you all the parameters you can use to format your date time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the output didn't seem to work, see the output:

https://jsfiddle.net/dekus90e/

If you look at array number [716] after formatting to the week the result given is '49'. However, in the original unformatted array, looking at element [716] the date is 12/05/2016. The week for date 12/05/2016 is week 19 so this doesn't seem to have worked

Comment: When interpreting date formats, using "/" in the format indicates it is in a MM/DD/YYYY format, based on this, 12/05/2016 would yield a week of 49 which is correct. However, it sounds like you are intending to use a DD/MM/YYYY format, for which you need to use "-", such as 12-05-2016. You can do a str_replace("/", "-", $h['0']) in order to have it interpreted in that format.